# How to decode an ASN1 encoded data(nested structured data) using pyasn1?

Tags: python, python-2.7, asn.1

My data should be able to fetch like the following way..

**Example Structure:-**

```
    listOfVolumes: -> SequenceOf
         ChangeOfCharCondition -> Sequence
                dataUplink: 9612742 -> Integer   
                dataDownlink: 216449 -> Integer
                changeCondition: qoSChange (0) -> Enumerated
                Time: 1206202320082b0530 -> OctetString

         ChangeOfCharCondition -> Sequence
                qosNegotiated: 0223921f9396979774f9ffff -> OctetString
                dataUplink: 57664480 -> Integer
                dataDownlink: 1460443 -> Integer
                changeCondition: recordClosure (2) -> Enumerated
                Time: 1206210017072b0530 -> OctetString
```

How do i decode a data encoded(bytearray) in this particular format?

I could decode it , if it is only a single SEQUENCE within the SEQUENCEOF structure,
but it is quite hard to me to loop over the data more than one time , can any one please
suggest me a better method to sort out this issue? Any advise is valuable for me..
Thaks in advance ..
**Sample code :**

```
class ChangeCondition(univ.Enumerated):

     namedValues = namedval.NamedValues(
        ('qoS', 0),
        ('Time', 1),
        ('Closure', 2),
        ('ContinueOngoing', 3),
        ('RetryandTerminateOngoing', 4),
        ('TerminateOngoing', 5),
        ('cGI', 6),
        ('rAI', 7),
        ('dT', 8),
        ('dT-Removal', 9))
        subtypeSpec = univ.Enumerated.subtypeSpec + \
                constraint.SingleValueConstraint(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

class ChangeOfCharCondition(univ.Sequence):

    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
    namedtype.OptionalNamedType('Negotiated', univ.OctetString().subtype(
        implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 2))),
    namedtype.OptionalNamedType('dataUplink', univ.Integer().subtype(
        implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 3))),
    namedtype.OptionalNamedType('dataDownlink', univ.Integer().subtype(
        implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 4))),
    namedtype.NamedType('changeCondition', ChangeCondition().subtype(
        implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 5))),
    namedtype.OptionalNamedType('Time', univ.OctetString().subtype(
        implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 6)))
       )

class ListOfVolumes(univ.SequenceOf):

    tagSet = baseTagSet = tag.initTagSet(tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext,tag.tagFormatSimple, 12),)
    componentType = ChangeOfCharCondition()

class MyCdr(univ.Set):

     tagSet = baseTagSet = tag.initTagSet(tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext,tag.tagFormatSimple, 21))
    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
    namedtype.OptionalNamedType('listOfVolumes', ListOfVolumes()))
```

My data is something like as follows,

```
bytearray(b'\xb5\x81\x2a\xac(0&\xa2\x0e\x81\x0c\x01#Q\x1f\x93\x96HHt\xf9\xff\xff\x83\x02\x06x\x84\x02\x13m\x85\x01\x02\x86\t6\x05"#\x12E+\x050')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your encoding contains a valid SEQUENCE OF items and you defined your pyasn1 data structures accordingly, pyasn1 decoder should be able to loop over all SEQUENCE OF instances  all by itself.

Could you post your pyasn1 specification of your data structure?

Comment: I have updated my query with sample code by which am trying to decode it. You may please refer to it and let me know where am went wrong? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

If you have the formal ASN.1 grammar for all these data structures, it would be helpful if you publish it here.

Your general approach looks correct, however the way you do ASN.1 tagging is suspicious.

From your initial description of the grammar, it looks like you should be able to decode your bytearray by calling pyasn1:

```
decoder.decode(mybytearray, asn1Spec=ListOfVolumes())
```

e.g. passing ListOfVolumes() class instance as a top-level prototype object to the decoder. If it fails it may be due to incorrect tagging.

To dig deeper it may help to enable pyasn1 debugging:

```
from pyasn1 import debug
debug.setLogger(debug.Debug('all')
```

and see what tags are read from bytearray and what objects from your specification match them.